Is the average person capable of adapting to a lower oxygen content in the air than earth, given enough time to slowly acclimate?
The concept of my world rests essentially on voluntary migration of populations to other planets either for colonization or relocation.
If the desired destination planet had significantly lower oxygen content, or “thinner air” similar to air on earth at high altitudes, could the average human acclimate given enough time?
Often, high altitude mountain climbers will bivouac at certain points in the ascent to adjust to the changes in oxygen content in order to retain consciousness.
Similarly, the idea is that the vessels of transport for these colonists would gradually decrease oxygen content over the voyage in order to acclimate the passengers for the destination planet. However, I’m unsure if the ability to adapt is constant across most people and if not what types would struggle most with these changes.
And if a large population could adapt, would there be any long term effects on health in such an environment?
Lots of micro questions in there, but essentially:
Could an average human adapt to a lower oxygen content environment given enough time to adapt?
If not, which would struggle?
If so, would there be long term side effects for this adjustment on the population.
It’s my first time posting a question here. I will endeavor to watch this post closely in case clarification is needed on anything I said and formatting critique is appreciated.
Thank you.
EDIT: Accidentally implicated oxygen content in air as an equivalent to air pressure. Since fixed. Thank you to Jon Custer, for pointing it out.

O2 percentage and overall pressure are different. Which do you mean?

I think you need to be clear about what "significantly lower" means here? Put it in altitude terms, perhaps. People live at altitudes that have an effective oxygen level about 55% of sea level. You can buy oxygen reduction equipment to simulate lower oxygen for training: see https://hypoxico.com/ for example (no affiliation) - but there are apparently limits to how far this can be pushed.

I agree in hindsight a more specific description would have been more helpful. However, for the sake of not invalidating the already well researched answers below, I will keep it as it is for now… perhaps if this vagueness becomes a problem later in my writing, I will write a more targeted and specific question then. Thank you.

Anecdata: the USAF Academy is at an elevation of 7,000+ feet. Upon arrival there, despite being in quite good condition, I did feel short of breath! Got acclimated. That issue did often seem to play a role when college sports teams "from lower altitudes" came to compete at USAFA! :)

Simply said: not too much.
To understand why, you should familiarize with the concept of death zone (emphasis mine):

In mountaineering, the death zone refers to altitudes above a certain point where the pressure of oxygen is insufficient to sustain human life for an extended time span. This point is generally tagged as 8,000 m (26,000 ft), where atmospheric pressure is less than 356 millibars (10.5 inHg; 5.16 psi).
Humans have survived for 2 years at 5,950 m (19,520 ft) [475 millibars (14.0 inHg; 6.89 psi) of atmospheric pressure], which appears to be near the limit of the permanently tolerable highest altitude. At extreme altitudes, above 7,500 m (24,600 ft) [383 millibars (11.3 inHg; 5.55 psi) of atmospheric pressure], sleeping becomes very difficult, digesting food is near-impossible, and the risk of HAPE or HACE increases greatly.
In the death zone and higher, no human body can acclimatize. The body uses up its store of oxygen faster than it can be replenished. An extended stay in the zone without supplementary oxygen will result in deterioration of body functions, loss of consciousness, and ultimately, death.

That said, below the death zone acclimatization is possible:

The human body can adapt to high altitude through both immediate and long-term acclimatization. At high altitude, in the short term, the lack of oxygen is sensed by the carotid bodies, which causes an increase in the breathing depth and rate (hyperpnea). However, hyperpnea also causes the adverse effect of respiratory alkalosis, inhibiting the respiratory center from enhancing the respiratory rate as much as would be required. Inability to increase the breathing rate can be caused by inadequate carotid body response or pulmonary or renal disease.
Full acclimatization requires days or even weeks. Gradually, the body compensates for the respiratory alkalosis by renal excretion of bicarbonate, allowing adequate respiration to provide oxygen without risking alkalosis. It takes about four days at any given altitude and can be enhanced by drugs such as acetazolamide. Eventually, the body undergoes physiological changes such as lower lactate production (because reduced glucose breakdown decreases the amount of lactate formed), decreased plasma volume, increased hematocrit (polycythemia), increased RBC mass, a higher concentration of capillaries in skeletal muscle tissue, increased myoglobin, increased mitochondria, increased aerobic enzyme concentration, increase in 2,3-BPG, hypoxic pulmonary vasoconstriction, and right ventricular hypertrophy. Pulmonary artery pressure increases in an effort to oxygenate more blood.
Full hematological adaptation to high altitude is achieved when the increase of red blood cells reaches a plateau and stops. The length of full hematological adaptation can be approximated by multiplying the altitude in kilometres by 11.4 days.

To go from mountaineering to any other place with low oxygen content, keep in mind that what matters is the gas partial pressure: 20% of 356 mbar is about 70 mbar. If there is more than that partial pressure, you are not in the death zone.

I wouldn't be surprised, if in a few decades mountaineers would often undergo gene therapy to get genes that are common in height adapted populations. I wonder how far you can get with this.

@TheDyingOfLight This answer already covers that: "Humans have survived for 2 years at 5,950 m (19,520 ft) [475 millibars (14.0 inHg; 6.89 psi) of atmospheric pressure], which appears to be near the limit of the permanently tolerable highest altitude." And in practice, the highest permanent settlements on Earth still cap out at around 5,000m. Daniel R. Collins' answer goes into this more.

I wouldn't call a pressure of 1/3 of the standard pressure "not too much".

You can't just look at the partial pressure of oxygen in figuring the death zone.  Total pressure becomes relevant because there is no such thing as 100% O2 in the lungs--there's always some evaporation.  At 100% O2 at minimum pressure this becomes important.

so in theory, those other worlds with "death zone" low oxygen in the atmosphere could still be survivable at very low altitudes (= higher air pressure), or in artificially overpressurized hab-domes?

It's fantastic what adaption mechanisms nature has in store. Probably half a billion years old.

When I visited Peru, I recall seeing a museum exhibit there highlighting the fact that even though the population of indigenous Quechua people have evolved over some 7,000 years to adapt better to high-altitude living, even they recognize a certain "death zone" above which no one has ever been able to live. (Unfortunately, I can't recall exactly what it's called in the native language.)
Generally populations living above 2,500 meters are counted as living at high altitudes, which accounts for about 1% of the world's population (per Wikipedia):

High-altitude adaptation in humans is an instance of evolutionary
modification in certain human populations, including those of Tibet in
Asia, the Andes of the Americas, and Ethiopia in Africa, who have
acquired the ability to survive at altitudes above 2,500 meters (8,200
ft). This adaptation means irreversible, long-term physiological
responses to high-altitude environments associated with heritable
behavioral and genetic changes. While the rest of the human population
would suffer serious health consequences at high altitudes, the
indigenous inhabitants of these regions thrive in the highest parts of
the world. These humans have undergone extensive physiological and
genetic changes, particularly in the regulatory systems of oxygen
respiration and blood circulation when compared to the general lowland
population.
Around 81.6 million humans (approximately 1.1% of the world's human
population) live permanently at altitudes above 2,500 meters (8,200
ft), which would seem to put these populations at risk for chronic
mountain sickness (CMS). However, the high-altitude populations in
South America, East Africa, and South Asia have lived there for
millennia without apparent complications. This special adaptation is
now recognized as an example of natural selection in action. The
adaptation of the Tibetans is the fastest known example of human
evolution, as it is estimated to have occurred around 1,000 BCE. to
7,000 BCE.

In Peru, for example, it's estimated that about 8 million people live above 2,500 meters. But the number above 5,000 meters is only about 20 thousand, and researchers studying the issue globally apparently don't bother to include any category above 5,500 meters. E.g.: see Dataset_S01 in Tremblay and Ainslie, "Global and country-level estimates of human population at high altitude" (2021). This is still quite some distance below the accepted death zone of around 8,000 meters.
On Quora, a very similar question was answered by a poster representing themselves as Daniel Dvorkin (PhD in bioinformatics & biostatistics, U. Colorado School of Medicine), specializing in high-altitude hypoxia research, and he said this:

As best we can figure out, every human being has a natural ceiling
beyond which they can’t acclimate... Most people are fine up to about
3000m / 9800 ft... At 4000 m / 13000 ft, nearly everyone will have
some difficulty, and won’t really acclimate no matter how long they
stay...
Himalayans, Andeans, and Ethiopian Highlanders are the only
populations in the world who have lived at these altitudes for long
enough to develop significant genetic adaptations. (Of course there
are many other places where people live at high altitude, but the
populations haven’t been there very long in evolutionary terms.)
People from these groups, whether they themselves live at high
altitude or not, tend to have a higher ceiling: 5000 m / 16000 ft is
about average, and for a few lucky individuals it’s 5500 m / 18000 ft...
Everest is 8849 m / 29032 ft: about 3300 m / 11000 ft more than the
highest human ceilings... Sorry, you can’t acclimate to that. No one
can.

A few more items of interest:

Effects of high altitude on humans
High-altitude living has changed more than just the genes of some Peruvians


I think that the Sherpas here would be the best example to compare with. They have adapted to live at abnormally high altitudes(3340m), where less oxygen is available(0.67 of sea level pressure). There isn't much difference for them at that altitude, however, when they come down to sea level they tend to be a lot more physically capable than most people due to adaptations such as larger lung capacity. Also, people could likely adapt to slower O2 content en route, as this is why mountain climbers do as well. They tend to spend time at higher altitudes to acclimate to the lower oxygen content. A similar thing can be done here, and in the long-term, as the Sherpas have shown, suffer few ill effects.

"Higher lung capacity in Sherpas" sounds more like a genetic adaption to me - Sherpas have lived at those altitudes for dozens or hundreds of generations - than an acclimatization the average person could achieve in a lifetime.

@Guntram Blohm They did ask for long-term effects, and I wasn't sure what they meant by that so went for the really long-term.

Yes - look at the altitudes that some Peruvian people live at, for example.
Given enough time, it seems reasonable to assume that even lower oxygen levels would be survivable.
Depending on timescales and levels, one might expect the population to evolve a larger average lung capacity - I understand that athletes typically have measurably larger capacity than average, merely from exercise - and that is without any long-term evolution.

I was going to mention Peruvian populations with the exact opposite conclusion. My understanding (based on one visit) is that for centuries there have been certain natives living at abnormally high altitudes, but there's still a "death zone" above which no population was ever able to intrude.

@DanielR.Collins multiple other factors, in addition to oxygen levels, can prevent high elevation settlements. Including, but not limited to, scarcity of food and the overall weather.

I also thought the Sherpa people were the only who have actually achieved some genetic adaption to the high altitudes. But then the subject is probably rife with hearsay info and just plain gossip. ;)

@Karl, it's complicated.  The peoples of the Andes have an altitude adaptation that's basically "flatlanders, but more so".  The peoples of the Tibetan Plateau have a unique adaptation, one that isn't simply a stronger version of the flatlander adaptation.

It depends, and is idiosyncratic.
Basically, you use about 0.2 pressure-atmospheres of oxygen to respire. You can go all the way up to about 1 atm without too much trouble (higher risk of atelectasis is about the worst of it, unless you have one of several rare problems that will kill you).
The percentage of oxygen has very little to do with that. So, that can be 10% of an ambient 2 atm pressure, 50% of 0.4 atm, etc. There are a few other constraints that start coming in, like you can't have a high carbon dioxide ambient partial pressure, and ambient pressures around 4 atm start getting scary in different ways.
But there are a lot of ways oxygen could be "lower", and you would be fine without any adaptation.
John West (a big name in pulmonology) put together an expedition to Everest in the 1980s, where everyone went up to altitude then ran experiments on themselves. (I'm assuming this made the IRB approval easier, and scored them a trip to Everest.) He edited a collection of their findings titled "High Altitude and Man" (https://www.amazon.com/dp/0683089455). If you want a detailed description of various physiological effects including adaptation, that's probably the best place to research further.

1 atm of O2 partial pressure is unhealty already, most people develop  symptoms after an hours or so. At ~ 1.5 atm, the timescale after which bad effects develop shortens drastically, 02 becomes more or less instantly toxic. Space programs have established that a partial pressure of 0.65 atm O2 can be breathed for a long time (weeks) without known adverse effects.
